Redundancy problem with SFSpeechRecognizer
I am trying to use Swift's SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest to transcribe audio to text. This works with ease if I have just one file to transcribe.  However, with multiple files I ran into what seems to be a concurrency issue. If I didn't wait for a file to be completely transcribed, result.isFinal == true, I kept running over the process and it wouldn't transcribe any of them.
Below is the closest I've come to making it work, but somehow to my eye's it still seems kludgy.
Is there a cleaner way to make sure I only transcribe one file at a time, i.e. wait for the results to come back?
One thing I'll note is that placing: defer { transcriptionSemaphore.signal() } in speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in would always call signal() way too early. From all the debugging the best I could come up with is that perhaps defer was being called when if result.isFinal == false, which I do not handle.
func sayWhat() {
    
    if items.isEmpty && !selectedMasterList.isEmpty {
        //fill custom dictionary
    }
    
    //retrieve all files to transcribe
    let files = fetchFilesWithPrefix(prefix: "T", invName: invName)
    for file in files{
        
        var player: AVAudioPlayer? = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: file)
        let duration = player?.duration ?? 0.0
        player = nil
        transcribeAudioFileTester(url: file, preferredWords: items,
                            filename: file.lastPathComponent, timePlace: timeCounter)
        timeCounter += duration
    }
}


private func transcribeAudioFileTester(url: URL, preferredWords: [String], filename: String, timePlace: Double) {
    transcriptionQueue.async { // Queue each task serially
        
        self.transcriptionSemaphore.wait()
        

        guard SFSpeechRecognizer.authorizationStatus() == .authorized else {
            print("Speech recognizer not authorized")
            self.transcriptionSemaphore.signal()
            return
        }

        guard let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US")),
              speechRecognizer.isAvailable else {
            print("Speech recognizer is not available at the moment.")
            self.transcriptionSemaphore.signal()
            return
        }

        let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: url)
        request.contextualStrings = preferredWords
        request.taskHint = .dictation
        request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true

        speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Recognition error for \(url.lastPathComponent): \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.transcriptionSemaphore.signal()
                return
            }

            guard let result = result else {
                print("No results were returned.")
                self.transcriptionSemaphore.signal()
                return
            }

            if result.isFinal {
                let recognizedText = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                print("Final recognized text:", recognizedText)
                self.transcriptionSemaphore.signal()
            }
        }
    }
}


I'm wondering if when it detects a "pause", it think that the transcript ended?

@Larme I don't believe that's it. I don't know much about SFSpeechRecognizer  but I tried testing with pauses and it handles it well.

My suggestion is you could consider convert your code to async await, also with async await, you can handle error properly:
func sayWhat() {
        ...
        Task {
            for file in files{
                var player: AVAudioPlayer? = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: file)
                let duration = player?.duration ?? 0.0
                player = nil
                try? await transcribeAudioFileTester(url: file, preferredWords: items,
                                    filename: file.lastPathComponent, timePlace: timeCounter) // <- handle error here
                timeCounter += duration
            }
        }
    }
    
    func transcribeAudioFileTester(url: URL, preferredWords: [String], filename: String, timePlace: Double) async {
        withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            ...
            speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Recognition error for \(url.lastPathComponent): \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    return
                }
                
                guard let result = result else {
                    print("No results were returned.")
                    continuation.resume()
                    return
                }
                
                if result.isFinal {
                    let recognizedText = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                    print("Final recognized text:", recognizedText)
                    continuation.resume()
                }
            }
        }
    }

Another appraoch is recursive to acheive your goal:
func transcribeAudioFileTester(url: URL, preferredWords: [String], filenames: [String], currIndex: Int, timePlace: Double) {
    transcriptionQueue.async { // Queue each task serially
        ...

        speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Recognition error for \(url.lastPathComponent): \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.transcribeAudioFileTester
                return
            }

            guard let result = result else {
                print("No results were returned.")
                self.transcribeAudioFileTester
                return
            }

            if result.isFinal {
                let recognizedText = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                print("Final recognized text:", recognizedText)
                self.transcribeAudioFileTester
            }
        }
    }
}

